# Cannot use begin split. Receive a "missing $ inserted" while in equation mode

Tags: equations, amsmath

I want to have a 2 line aligned equation. When I try to compile the following code I receive a few errors and I cannot understand why.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
n \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{v} + \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \nabla n + \frac{\partial n}{\partial t} &= 0 \\

n \sum_{i=1}^3\Big( \frac{\partial\dot{q_i}}{\partial q_i}+\frac{\partial\dot{v_i}}{\partial v_i} \Big) + \boldsymbol{v}\cdot \nabla n + \frac{\partial n}{\partial t} &= 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

I recieve the errors:

```
Missing $ inserted
Missing \endgroup inserted
Display math should end with $$.
```

Comment: don't put blank lines in display math

Comment: unrelated but `\Big(` should be `\Bigl(` and similarly `\Bigr)`

Comment: The issue of inappropriate blank lines in a display-math environment has got to be dupe.

Answer (score 0):

The environment `align` and `aligned` are probably more suited than `split` for what you are looking for. Look at the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
n \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{v} + \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \nabla n + \frac{\partial n}{\partial t} &= 0 \\
n \sum_{i=1}^3\Big( \frac{\partial\dot{q_i}}{\partial q_i}+\frac{\partial\dot{v_i}}{\partial v_i} \Big) + \boldsymbol{v}\cdot \nabla n + \frac{\partial n}{\partial t} &= 0
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Another solution, would be to use sub-equations as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
n \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{v} + \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \nabla n + \frac{\partial n}{\partial t} &= 0 \\
n \sum_{i=1}^3\Big( \frac{\partial\dot{q_i}}{\partial q_i}+\frac{\partial\dot{v_i}}{\partial v_i} \Big) + \boldsymbol{v}\cdot \nabla n + \frac{\partial n}{\partial t} &= 0
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Hope that helps.

Romain

Comment: but now you have two equation numbers. with split is only one ...

Comment: Yes, using subequations is probably a much cleaner solution.

Comment: no :-). what op desire, is one number, so it use `split` ... error in his/her code example is empty line as pointed David in his comment. also use `\biggl(` and `\biggr)` is more correct selection for parenthesis.